# akamai osmf live stream connection woes

Tags: actionscript-3, stream, live, akamai, osmf

I know this stream works because of two reasons:

- 1) It works OUTSIDE of OSMF
- 2) It works in the akamai support player: http://support.akamai.com/flash/  I don't believe the current akamai support player is using OSMF (which is suprising since they built the predecessor to osmf..)

My question is: How in the world do I play a live stream in osmf? This should be very simple if not automatic. However, I'm getting the following error when I try to play a working live stream:

```
Error: Stream not found
```

Which is a bunch of garbage since a non-OSMF player can play it. I have the Akamai Basic Streaming plugin which doesn't seem to be helping either.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome. I've been n00bized again. That'll learn me.

I scoured through the source again and found out it's this easy:

```
var mediaPlayerSprite:MediaPlayerSprite = new MediaPlayerSprite();
var videoElement:VideoElement = new VideoElement();

videoElement.resource = new StreamingURLResource("rtmp://cp34973.live.edgefcs.net/live/Flash_Live_Benchmark@632", StreamType.LIVE);

addChild(mediaPlayerSprite);
mediaPlayerSprite.media = videoElement;
```

Until next time, this was "Stump yourself". Thank you, and good night.